# Webpack vendor chunk is too big

Tags: webpack

I digged through all the internet to just not find how to divide `node_modules` chunk (which weights ~2mb) into smaller ones.

I use Webpack 4 (with Vue.js if that matters) and

```
optimization: { splitChunks: {chunks: 'all'}}
```

setting. And all I get is separate `vendor.js` and `app.js` file:
[image]

I'm really exhausted by Webpack's un-configurableness - shouldn't it be made by default? This app is like 5 pages big and I wouldn't even say it's a medium size app.

Comment: You can use `webpack-bundle-analyzer` to check which module affecting in increase in size. Then remove it or use alternative module with same functionality but lesser size.

Comment: or you can disable those warnings: `performance: {hints: false}`

Comment: Also try using `mode: production` in your configuration to see the difference in size.